# Bing Maps display North America top-left corner of map

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am trying to display North America/Canada on top-left corner of the map.

Now using the center of mapoptions won't help as it changes based on screen size.

I got litter further by using something like this:

```
var viewRect = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromCorners(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(-37.71859032558814, -95.2734375), // african ocean 
            new Microsoft.Maps.Location(63.704722429433225, 101.25)
        );
map.setView({ bounds: viewRect });
```

Now this is better than focusing on the center as it displays North America on top-left of bigger screen, but the screen size is still an issue.

Is anyone aware of any other methodologies which allow to display North America on top-left corner of screen irrespective of screen size?

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your zoom is changing or static?

Comment: Zoom is not static. Here is what I did, see answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did, focus on certain center to modify map view during loading based on different standard screen sizes.

```
function GetBestViewBasedOnScreenSize() {
var viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth, viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
console.log("changed the height is " + viewportHeight + " the widht is " + viewportWidth);
console.log('view 1');
if (viewportWidth > 300 && viewportWidth <= 600) {

}
else if (viewportWidth > 300 && viewportWidth <= 1000) {

    console.log('900 - 1200');
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(26.628887011185398, 27.903637500000013);
    map.setView({ center: center, zoom: 2 });
    console.log('center is ' + '26.628887011185398 27.903637500000013');
}
else if (viewportWidth > 1000 && viewportWidth <= 1200) { // most common 
   var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(13.4549, 47.9427);
    map.setView({ center: center, zoom: 2 });
    console.log('center is ' + '13.4549c47.9427');
}
else if (viewportWidth > 1200 && viewportWidth <= 1300) { // for 1280
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(29.87829481517158, -24.661942570032593);
    map.setView({ center: center, zoom: 3 });
    console.log('center is ' + '29.87829481517158 - 24.661942570032593');
}
else if (viewportWidth > 1300 && viewportWidth <= 1400) { // for 1360
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(33.322323930108524, -12.533881250000025);
    map.setView({ center: center, zoom: 3 });
    console.log('center is ' + '33.322323930108524 - 12.533881250000025');
}
else if (viewportWidth > 1400 && viewportWidth <= 1500) { // for 1440
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(18.522390173568184, -3.920600000000025);
    map.setView({ center: center, zoom: 3 });
    console.log('center is ' + '18.522390173568184 - 3.920600000000025');
}
else if (viewportWidth > 1500 && viewportWidth <= 1600) { // for 1600
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(15.666478131159806, 9.790337499999975);
    map.setView({ center: center, zoom: 3 });
    console.log('center is ' + '15.666478131159806 9.790337499999975');
}
else if (viewportWidth > 1600 && viewportWidth <= 1920) { // for 1920
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(10.704938710599649, 37.73955624999998);
    map.setView({ center: center, zoom: 3 });
    console.log('center is ' + '10.704938710599649 37.73955624999998');
}
else if (viewportWidth > 1920 && viewportWidth <= 2400) {
    var center = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(4.78563220981988, 47.58330624999998);
    map.setView({ center: center, zoom: 3 });
    console.log('center is ' + '4.78563220981988 47.58330624999998 ');
} else {
    // load world 
}
```

}